# What is echo $? in linux terminal?

Tags: linux

I have tried those commands.

```
~$top
(ctrl + z)stopped the process
~$echo $?
147
~$top
(ctrl + c)killed the process
~$echo $?
0
```

What happened here, please explain it and why it showing some constant value. What is the meaning of those values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked @ http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is the exit status. Read about [bash special parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)

Comment: @g-v While technically true, that post doesn't answer what a return code of >=128 means. :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, agree, also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294056/how-to-lookup-the-meaning-of-exit-codes-for-linux-command-line-utilities

Comment: @g-v Jonathan Leffler's answer on that thread is excellent and I upvoted it. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: And finally http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074956/what-happens-when-you-hit-ctrlz-on-a-process for explanation about `^Z`.

Answer (score 28):

`$?` is the return code from the last run process. 0 means no error happened. Other values represent some kind of unusual condition.

Values 128 and above usually represent some kind of signal. 147 - 128 = 19, which means the program received signal 19 (`SIGSTOP` on Linux). Now, normally pressing ^Z sends `SIGTSTP` (a different signal from `SIGSTOP`), which probably meant that `top` caught that signal, did some (probably terminal-related) cleanup, and reissued `SIGSTOP` to actually suspend the program.

`top` also caught `SIGINT` (which is normally issued after pressing ^C), to do cleanup and exit cleanly (with exit value 0).

---

You can run `kill -l` to see what all the signal numbers are for the current platform. Note that the numbers are different for different platforms; for example, `SIGSTOP` is 17 on Darwin and 19 on Linux.

Answer (score 5):

`echo $?` returns the return value (exit status) of the last executed command (0 is usually `success`).

Comment: Hi, well my cpp program was supposed to return 1234 but the echo $? return 210, doesn't echo $? suppose to return also 1234?

Comment: @Tomer as far as I know Unix systems return 8 bit values (starting from 0 to 255) so `1234%256 = 210`. That is why you get that value. I haven't checked in Windows but make sure to read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149267/10540569)