# Why echo $? returns different value than expected?

Tags: bash, error-handling, compiler-errors, echo, exit

I know that `echo $?` returns the exit status of the previous process.
In my program I get `0` if my program ends with a status code of `0`. But when the program ends with status code `-1` `echo $?` shows `255`. Similar questions are there on StackOverflow, but is not explained why is it so. Plus one of the answers says generally values above `128` indicates some error and negative exit code. Like for example, `147` - we can get the real exit code by subtracting 128 from 147, 128 - 147 = -19, so the exit code was -19.
In my computer I find 256 as that number. For example 255 - 256 = -1, which was what my program was returning.
Why on different systems do these numbers vary 128, 256 and why can't they print the original negative code instead of adding these numbers to the original exit status code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For historical reasons, exit code is interpreted as unsigned one-byte value. "Normal" error codes are positive (<127), while "abnormal" error codes (e.g. those produced by terminating on signal) are negative (>=128).

Try pressing Ctrl-C on a `sleep 10` command. The exit code is 130.

127 is the result of "command not found".

It's really not a recommended practice to use negative error codes explicitly.

For more information, take a look at `wait()` man page (`man 2 wait`), in particular `WFEXITED()` and friends.

> WEXITSTATUS(status)
>
> returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of the **least significant 8 bits** of  the  status  argument  that  the
>   child  specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument for a return statement in main().  This macro should
>   only be employed if WIFEXITED returned true.

(Emphasis added)

Comment: Can you explain this to me:
    if(4>5) return 255;
    else return -1;
shows 255 in the terminal.
While
    if(10>1) return 255;
    else return -1;
Also shows 255 in the terminal

Comment: Suppose the program is complex enough to produce that much of error codes.

Comment: So, the upper limit to how many error codes we can return is `256` - using does 8 bits, after that the combination of the least significant 8 bits repeats itself.

Comment: Yes, no more than 255 - 0 is reserved for "success".

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457979/what-is-echo-in-linux-terminal) The answer by Chris Jester-Young has 128 as that number, so their system is using least significant 7 bits only.

Comment: As I said, please limit yourself to use values 1-126. If you need more than a handful, it's probably better to reconsider.

Comment: 128 is more than enough for me. :P